# How to get next day end of day date time from given Instant ? (Java)

Tags: java, date, time, java-time

I have an Instant Date, eg: `2020-03-09T20:13:57.089Z` and I want to find the end of next day in Instant, eg - `2020-03-10T23:59:59.089Z` (this would be the end of next day compared to the initial date)

How do I do this using Instant in Java?

Comment: Yes, use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. And no, don’t represent the end of the day as 23:59:59-dot-something. Represent it as the first moment of the next day. It’s much simpler and also more correct. Only always remember that the day lasts until that moment *exclusive*.

Comment: Where does the 0.089 seconds come from?  Or do you just want 23:59:59 exactly?

Comment: 1) You say "**midnight**" and you say `11:59:59.089Z`, which is **noon**, so which is it? --- 2) Is it a requirement to *retain* the `.089` milliseconds like you showed? If so, you should explicitly say so, to clarify your requirements.

Comment: *"`2020-03-10T11:59:59.089Z` (this would be the end of next day)"* I have never thought of **noon** (aka "midday") as being the "end of day" for anything. Are you *sure* you didn't mean `23:59:59`?

Comment: The title was revised by another user. I meant the end of next day, that's 23:59:59. I re-edited the title to match this. @Andreas

Comment: Ok, so for the *third time*: Sample shown time is **11**:59:59, which is **noon**, but you ask for "end of day", aka **midnight**, which is **23**:59:59. Please fix the discrepancy in your question text, i.e. change 11 to 23, *OR* change "end of day" / "midnight" to "middle of day" / "noon".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is converting `Instant` to `ZonedDateTime` with `UTC` timezone and modify the date as per requirement and then convert it back

**Midday :**

```
Instant result = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                        .plusDays(1).with(LocalTime.of(11,59,59,instant.getNano()))
                        .toInstant();
```

**End of day :**

```
Instant result = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                        .plusDays(1).with(LocalTime.of(23,59,59,instant.getNano()))
                        .toInstant();
```

Comment: try my updated code it gives exactly what you need for @YashDamani

Comment: Great answer. --- But, you should use `atOffset()` instead of `atZone()`.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. I made an error in my question which is my bad. Nevertheless, I updated my question and adjusted the solution accordingly. Thanks! @Deadpool

Answer (score 5):

If you want the actual midnight (00:00), you can use:

```
instant.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

Otherwise, another solution would be:

```
LocalDateTime ldt1 = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS), ZoneId.systemDefault());

ldt1 = ldt1
        .withHour(23)
        .withMinute(59)
        .withSecond(59);

Instant result = ldt1.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
```

Comment: no, I don't want the actual midnight, but the next day's (11:59). I'm sorry, should've been more clear with the question.

Comment: Instead of `ldt1.withHour(23).withMinute(59).withSecond(59)`, I think `ldt1.toLocalDate().atTime(23, 59, 59)` would be better, because it resets fractional seconds to 0, and it has fewer intermediate objects.

Comment: Thanks! I added 2 days and subtracted a second like you mentioned, and it worked. :) @Andreas

Comment: The conversion to/from `LocalDateTime` must be done with UTC time zone, otherwise the resulting time will not be `23:59:59Z`

Comment: That's true! Since Instant objects deal with UTC by default, converting it using Instant functions worked as well. @Andreas